# Template function broken after compiling with C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors

I have a very simple template function to compare the `rank` field of two `structs`:

```
template<typename T>
bool comp_rank(const T &a, const T &b){
    return a.rank < b.rank;
}
```

This worked fine, until I compiled with `-std=c++11`. Now, I get the error

```
error: parameter "b" is not a type name
      return a.rank < b.rank;
                      ^

./src/util.h(123): error: expected a ">"
      return a.rank < b.rank;
                       ^
```

What gives? This seems like basic syntax that I would surprised to find had changed after C++11.

Comment: Shot in the dark here.. Because I vaguely remember seeing a question similar to this the other day.. But could you try: `b.rank > a.rank` ?

Comment: Can you please also add the struct? A [mcve] will help us

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you use

```
using namespace std;
```

Because c++11 introduces a template `rank`

See here : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank

If you remove the `using` statement, everything compiles fine again!

Here is the error message given by gcc 8.2.1

```
main.cpp: In function 'bool comp_rank(const T&, const T&)':
main.cpp:41:23: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class> struct std::rank'
    return a.rank < b.rank;
```

It is not a good idea to use `using namespace ...` anyway. You gave already a good example ;)

Comment: @Anonymous: Sorry, i am not finished. Mouse event accident ;)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Please elaborate

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: I can reproduce the example and error when using the "using" statement.

Comment: @Klaus: You may be right, but we cannot really tell until OP posts a [mcve] or chimes in on this comment thread saying that fixed it. For now you're guessing.

Comment: @AndyG: Simply copy the posted code, add an empty main() and set "using namespace std" before and you got the error. What is not reproduceable here?@all: And thanks for the downvote... ;)

Comment: I didn't downvote you, sir. That is another assumption on your part.

Comment: @AndyG: Sorry, that was not directed to you;)

Comment: It really does reproduce: https://wandbox.org/permlink/upNfNBCO1KVannyu I would like to know why, though.

Comment: @krzaq Look at it as `a.rank<b .rank`. Since `std::rank` is a template it requires a closing `>` for `rank<b>` so you get that error message.

Comment: @Anonymous: would be nice if you could confirm that your problem relates to the using problem ... If so, accept please :-)

Comment: @DeiDei thanks! That makes sense, though I do wonder why external templates are even considered in this place. I can't think of an expression in the form of `obj.tmp<x>` that would make sense (now, `obj.*tmp<x>` on the other hand...)

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/aoY2jM).  This is why a mcve is important.  Without knowing what the OP is actually using all we can offer is a guess. (While this answer is right, unless the OP is explicitly including `<type_traits>`, it really should't error.  Unfortunetly gcc includes a lot of other headers if you just include `<iostream>` as you can see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/wO6IOI))

Comment: @NathanOliver _shouldn't_ is too strong of a word here, the implementation can include any standard header from any other standard header.

Comment: @krzaq `obj.tmp<x>` can be read as it is calling the template function `tmp` of the `obj` object and specifying the template parameter.  Since that is a legal thing to do you run into problems.

Comment: @NathanOliver Sorry, I meant for `tmp` to be an external class template, just like `rank` is in this case.

Comment: This worked. Actually, I didn't get rid of `using...` because my code is atrocious with `std::` everywhere. I just renamed the `rank` field of my struct to something else. am I able to write `vector` rather than `std::vector` without `using namespace std;`? Essentially I'd like the equivalent of the python-friendly form `from std import vector`

Comment: @Anonymous `using std::vector;`

Comment: FWIW I think this is a bug in both clang and gcc. Will be posting an answer.

Answer (score 7):

**Edit**: I've submitted a bug report to gcc [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88434). It's currently unconfirmed.

Given that you accepted [@Klaus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53712698/27678), your code looks something [like this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/upNfNBCO1KVannyu) (thanks @krzaq):

```
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

struct A{ int rank; };

template<typename T>
bool comp_rank(const T &a, const T &b){
    return a.rank < b.rank;
}

int main()
{
    A a{42}, b{0};
    comp_rank(a, b);
}
```

Both gcc (9.0.0 and earlier were tested), and clang (8.0.0 and earlier were tested) reject this code on the grounds that they are expecting the `id-expression` `a.rank<` to be the start of a template. According to the standard, this is the wrong interpretation. See [basic.lookup.classref]

> In a class member access expression, if the `.` or `->` token is
>   immediately followed by an identifier followed by a `<`, the *identifier*
>   must be looked up to determine whether the `<` is the beginning of a
>   template argument list or a less-than operator. The identifier
>   is first looked up in the class of the object expression. If the
>   identifier is not found, it is then looked up in the context of the
>   entire *postfix-expression* and shall name a class template.

The compiler *should have* looked up `a.rank` and discovered it to be an integer member of class `A`. [MSVC 19.00.23506  compiles it just fine](https://rextester.com/EEXXD47122)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is enlightening. Unfortunately I'm running this as a parallel job on a large machine, which makes playing with different compilers nontrivial -_-

Comment: Can you please fill the bug report? Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue that [CGW 1835](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1835) deal with, citing it here:

> According to 6.4.5 [basic.lookup.classref] paragraph
>
> In a class member access expression (8.2.5 [expr.ref]), if the . or -> token is immediately followed by an identifier followed by a <, the identifier must be looked up to determine whether the < is the beginning of a template argument list (17.2 [temp.names]) or a less-than operator. The identifier is first looked up in the class of the object expression. If the identifier is not found, it is then looked up in the context of the entire postfix-expression and shall name a class template.
>
> ```
> template<typename T> T end(T);
> template<typename T>
> bool Foo(T it) {
>     return it->end < it->end;
> }
> ```
>
> **since it is dependent and thus end cannot be looked up in the class of the object expression, it is looked up in the context of the postfix-expression. This lookup finds the function template, making the expression ill-formed.**
>
> One possibility might be to limit the lookup to the class of the object expression when the object expression is dependent.

---

```
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
bool comp_rank(const T &a, const T &b){
    return a.rank < b.rank; // fail
}
```

The error shows up even without instantiating the function template, the whole expression is dependent, hence they can't be looked up into the class scope. As the current wording of the standard is not clear if lookup for `rank` in the class scope will be deferred for dependent names or must be bound to names in the *context of the postfix-expression* that's what the CGW try to tackle.

a direct solution is to use parens:

```
template<typename T>
bool comp_rank(const T &a, const T &b){
    return (a.rank) < (b.rank);
}
```